# calculate monthly depreciation of an asset in asp.net using double line balance

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have successfully been able to calculate a monthly depreciable amount of an asset using straight line formula

I'm having issues using the doubline balance line formular as I'm not getting my expected result

```
formula  = (2* depreciation ) / lifeMonth
```

below is my backend code

```
  Dim acquiredDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(2019, 11, 15)
            Dim startMonth As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(2019, 11, 15)
            Dim depreciation As Double = "10000"
            Dim slavege As Double = "10"
            Dim lifeMonth As Integer = "12"
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
            dt.Columns.Add("Month")
            dt.Columns.Add("Depreciation", GetType(Decimal))
            dt.Columns.Add("Accumulated", GetType(Decimal))
            dt.Columns.Add("BookValue", GetType(Decimal))
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            Dim depreciationExpense As Double = (2 * depreciation) / lifeMonth
            Dim bookValue As Double = depreciation - depreciationExpense
            Dim newDepreciationExpense As Double = 0

            While startMonth < acquiredDate.AddMonths(lifeMonth)
                Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                dr("Month") = startMonth.ToString("MMM yyyy")
                dr("Depreciation") = depreciationExpense

                If i = 0 Then
                    dr("Accumulated") = Math.Round(depreciationExpense, 2)
                    dr("BookValue") = Math.Round(bookValue, 2)
                    newDepreciationExpense = depreciationExpense
                Else
                    newDepreciationExpense = newDepreciationExpense + depreciationExpense
                    bookValue = bookValue - depreciationExpense
                    dr("Accumulated") = Math.Round(newDepreciationExpense, 2)
                    dr("BookValue") = Math.Round(bookValue, 2)
                End If

                dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                startMonth = startMonth.AddMonths(1)
                i += 1
            End While

            Me.gvData.DataSource = dt
            Me.gvData.DataBind()
```

below is my front end(html)

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvData" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped table-depreciation">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Month" HeaderText="Month" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Depreciation" HeaderText="Depriciation Expenses" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Accumulated" HeaderText="Accumulate Deprication at Month-End" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BookValue" HeaderText="Book Value at Month-End" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

the result I'm getting

[image: result am getting]

my expected result

[image: expected_result]

Comment: Is this also known as Double Declining Balance? It has been quite a few years since my Accountant career.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: None of the `Covert.ToDateTime` methods will work with those parameters. You might try `Dim acquiredDate As New Date(2019, 11, 15)`

Comment: `depreciation`, `slavege` and `lifeMonth` are all declared as number types but you have tried to set the values to strings. Numbers surrounded by double quotes are strings.

Comment: @Mary, this is a double declining balance, and if you check my expected result screenshot  and screenshot of the result am getting, you would see that the  difference starts from jan 2020, that is the figures arent the the same and i believe the issue is  from my code, cuz my formula is correct. ive tried Dim acquiredDate As New Date(2019, 11, 15), yet the result is still the same

Comment: I guess I really don't understand your example. With a useful life of 12 months or less the purchase would be expensed immediately. Fully deductible in the year purchased. What asset class do you have that would depreciate over 12 months? Not at all familiar with tax law in Nigeria. Double Declining Balance front loads the deductions so, your deduction expense is greater in year one than straight line. Then is recalculated each year based on the declining balance.

Comment: @mary ok, kindly assist in writing the code for double line depreciation for me in asp.net(c# of vb)